# "Continual" if something undesirable happens or exists without stopping

Tags: adjectives, style, semantics

> If you are describing something **undesirable** which continues to happen
> or exist **without stopping**, it is better to use **continual** rather
> than *continuous*.
>
> *Life for her was a **continual struggle** because she was in **continual pain**.*
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/continual

Is the author right here?

Comment: Showing results for continual continuous
Search instead for continual continuos
continual/ continuous
The words continual and continuous are like twins: they both come from continue, but they get mad if you get them confused. Continual means start and stop, while continuous means never-ending. Continual things come and go, like arguments or rain.

Answer (score 1):

'Continual' refers to things that occur repeatedly. For example, "it continually rains in winter".

'Continuous' is used for things that occur without a break. For example, "it has rained continuously for 2 days".

There might be cases where the two words are interchangeable, but there are definitely cases where they are not. For example "*he continually failed at exams*" would mean that each time he took an exam, he failed. This would sound incorrect with 'continuously', as it would imply that he perpetually sat exams back to back without a break.

Comment: This question was asked three years ago. I don't get why people don't upvote this kind of answer. I really don't.